Angular Material Table sorting arrows not displaying
Angular17 with Material Table sorting arrows not displaying, I am using multiTemplateDataRows. Can any one point me where I am doing wrong. I am looking for Arrows to display before implementing sorting functionality. I am getting data from back end server and displaying in the table. Please let me know if you need mode code from typescript file.
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort multiTemplateDataRows class="mat-elevation-z8">
  @for (column of columnsToDisplay; track column) {
     <ng-container matColumnDef="{{column}}">
       <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>

        @if(column=='Sta'){
          DEP
        }@if(column=='event'){
          EVENT
        }
        @if(column=='srcTimestamp'){
          GENERATED TIME
        }
        @if(column=='insTimestamp'){
          RECORDED TIME
        }

      </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element[column]}} </td>
    </ng-container>
  }
  <ng-container matColumnDef="expand">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef aria-label="row actions">&nbsp;</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
      <button mat-icon-button aria-label="expand row" (click)="(expandedElement = expandedElement === element ? null : element); $event.stopPropagation()">
        @if (expandedElement === element) {
           <mat-icon>keyboard_arrow_up</mat-icon>
        } @else {
           <mat-icon>keyboard_arrow_down</mat-icon>
        }
      </button>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="expandedDetail">
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" [attr.colspan]="columnsToDisplayWithExpand.length">
      <div class="example-element-detail"
        [@detailExpand]="element == expandedElement ? 'expanded' : 'collapsed'">
        <div class="example-element-description">
          <textarea readonly matInput style="height: 200px; width:750px;overflow-y: auto;font-family: 'Bradley Hand', cursive;background-color: beige;">
            {{element.avroMsg |json}}
          </textarea>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button mat-button mat-raised-button [cdkCopyToClipboard]="element.avroMsg |json">Copy</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnsToDisplayWithExpand;sticky: true"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let element; columns: columnsToDisplayWithExpand;let index = dataIndex;"
    [ngClass]="{alternate: index % 2 == 0 }"
    class="example-element-row"
    [class.example-expanded-row]="expandedElement === element"
    (click)="expandedElement = expandedElement === element ? null : element">
  </tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['expandedDetail']" class="example-detail-row"></tr>
</table>


probably a copy paste issue, expandedElement is used everywhere

I found problem and is have to import MatSortModule in .ts file

nice work finding the solution It might be useful to add a bit more detail answer - I assume by "the .ts file" you mean the component .ts file? Also - don't forget to mark your answer as accepted :)
